# Capillary turned upside down

Tags: fluid-statics, capillary-action

I have a glass capillary filled with water at half volume. The meniscus shape is well known. I turn the capillary upside down. The water does not flow out. What shape the new meniscus will be? Roughly.

Comment: If you ignore the effect of gravity on the water surface then due to adhesive and cohesive force the meniscus shape would remain same. But due to gravitational attraction the meniscus shape will be convex.

Comment: Up and down involve gravity. If convex, how will water wet glass?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting

Answer (score 1):

Within the bounds of advancing/receding contact angle hysteresis, the contact angle will be the same whatever gravity orientation, set only by the interface energies. If the radius of the capillary is large enough, you can see the effect of gravity which will reduce the curvature at the center of an "inverted" meniscus of wetting liquid. If the radius is too large, this will lead to the destabilization of the meniscus, a bubble will form and the water will flow out.